# For positive weight directed graphs, in what case is the most direct path not the shortest?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, directed-graph

Basically, in a graph where the weights are the Euclidean distance, is something like Dijkstra's algorithm really necessary or is a direct path to your destination always the shortest?

I'm really asking for a general answer to this question, however I think this is always true for the case given below.

`==================================`

I'm almost 100% sure that this is the case if the edges form regular polygons.

These paths have no dead ends, i.e., there exists some path from any vertex `v1` to any other vertex `v2`.

By regular polygon I mean the graph is formed by edge connection of regular polygons of `n` vertices, without ever forming other polygons in the process.

`n = 5`

```
 . .
.   .
  .   .
   . .
  .   .
    .   .
     . .
```

`n = 4`

```
    . . . .
  . . . . .
  . . .
    . .
```

`n = 3`

```
  .     . .
 . . . . . .
. . . .   . .
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "if the edges form regular polygons"? It seems like you have a very restricted type of graph in mind, for which a simpler approach than Dijkstra's might very well be optimal. In general, in graphs with Euclidean distance, a greedy approach might not be optimal (the greedy choice might lead to a dead end, for instance).

Comment: In this case, there are no dead ends, all paths eventually lead to the destination.

Comment: Isn't your n=3 case a counter-example? Path from upper left to lower right will be longer if it goes down to bottom first.

Comment: It would never go down to the bottom first, because once it goes down one, going to the right one will bring it closer to the destination, it will always try to greedily get closer to the destination. I'll remove the rectangles paragraph since it's misleading.

Comment: A greedy algorithm won't always work if there are obstacles.

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle You are right, though this is only true for certain kinds of obstacle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a counterexample:

`n = 4`

```
. . . . . . . .
. . . . .   . .
. . . . .   . .
. . .       . .
. . . . .   . .
. . . . .   . .
. . . . .   . . 
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
```

Basically, if there is any non-symmetrical gap in the graph, then the greedy algorithm, which always selects the nearest vertex to the end vertex, *may* select a vertex which forces it to take a longer path.

However, the greedy algorithm will always work for paths with no obstacles, or paths with symmetrical obstacles if the starting point halves the obstacle. In fact, an algorithm which could simply find the shortest path around each individual obstacle would provide solutions nearly as good as Dijkstra's without as much overhead, as long as there are no dead ends.

But implementing such an algorithm is the same as implementing Dijkstra's on sub-paths of the total path, and is therefore pretty pointless, unless you really need to reduce the computational resources required.